# Is there any way to read mobile phone's IMEI number from expo?

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, expo

I am building a react native mobile app using expo. I want to access client's mobile IMEI number and get it into the front end.I don't know how to do  that. Is it possible to do with expo?

I tried react-native-device-info

Comment: Probably https://gist.github.com/mkjangid/d717f4f7c236c8085c1597e163951612

Answer (score 0):

Expo does not provide direct access to the IMEI (International Mobile Equipment Identity) number of a mobile phone due to privacy and security concerns.

Comment: what is the easiest way to acess IMEI number?